# Objective C Preprocessor: Getting current class

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to get the class of the current scope in the preprocessor?

Currently, what I am doing is the following:

I have a macro:

```
#define DATA_SOURCE_DEF_CONSTR(CLASS) + (CLASS *)dataSource { \
CLASS *source = [[[CLASS alloc] init] autorelease]; \
return source; \
}
```

and then I am using that macro in a lot of classes like:

```
DATA_SOURCE_DEF_CONSTR(SpecialDataSource)
```

I would like to something like:

```
#define DATA_SOURCE_DEF_CONSTR + (__CLASS__ *)dataSource { \
__CLASS__ *source = [[[__CLASS__ alloc] init] autorelease]; \
return source; \
}
```

And call it like:

```
@implementation ...

DATA_SOURCE_DEF_CONSTR

...

@end
```

Is that possible in Objective-C with the preprocessor?

Comment: In this particular case you can write `#define DATA_SOURCE_DEF_CONSTR + (id)dataSource { return [[[[self class] alloc] init] autorelease]; }`

Comment: You can use typeof, in case, you need that local variable strongly typed     #define DATA_SOURCE_DEF_CONSTR + (id)dataSource { \
typeof(self)source = [[[self alloc] init] autorelease]; \
return source; \
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get what you're trying to accomplish.  Why not just add a category to NSObject, like:

```
@implementation NSObject (handyConstructor)

+ autoreleasedInstance { return [[[self class] alloc] init] autorelease]; }

@end
```

Is there some reason why you want this to be done by the preprocessor in particular?

Comment: It would be cleaner if I could do it with the preprocessor, because this way I am always getting a compiler warning that the return type is not exactly the type of the variable that I am assigning it too. Of course the type matches, but the compiler just can't see it, so I have to do a manual cast to silence that warning. It would be cleaner if I could avoid that manual cast with the preprocessor generating appropriately typed constructors.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new keyword, `instancetype`, that perhaps could help you; more [here](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/). For your example:

```
#define DATA_SOURCE_DEF_CONSTR + (instancetype)dataSource { \
return [[[[self class] alloc] init] autorelease]; \
}
```

Comment: Can instancetype be used outside of a method declaration though? This would be great for factory building macros.

Comment: @Dustin No it can't, unfortunately. Not yet anyway. It can only be used as the return type of a method declaration/definition.

Comment: You can `typeof(self)` in a declaration, e.g. `__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;`.